# Access enumeration member of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, enumeration, member

I'm trying to pass an "Options"-Object to the constructor of another object.
Options have enumerations which I try to read in another file.

js/mainApp.js:

```
square = new World(20, 20, null, 0);

var opts = new Options(MODE.SINGLE, REGION.MIDDLE_EAST);
world = new World(0, 0, "img/whatever.png", opts);
```

js/options.js :

```
var MODE = {
    SINGLE : 1,
    MULTI  : 2
};

var REGION = {
    MIDDLE_EAST : { xTranslate : -2300, yTranslate: -700, scale : 1.2}
};

function Options(MODE, REGION) {
    this.mode = MODE;
    this.region = REGION;
}
```

Now in the World constructor I'm getting the error "`opts.region is undefined`" for the second alert. For some reason the first alert shows the expected "`{ xTranslate : -2300, yTranslate: -700, scale : 1.2}`"

js/options.js:

```
var World = ExtendingSomething.extend(
{
    initialize: function(x, y, imageURL, opts) {
        alert (JSON.stringify(opts.region));
        alert (JSON.stringify(opts.region.scale));
        ...
    }
}
);
```

Edit: I added few information

I don't understand why I'm getting this error `is undefined` while it works in
[in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCa2m/) (thanks for creating to Thomas C. G. de Vilhena).

Maybe it's a problem that I'm using different files?
still: Why is there no problem with the call `opts.region`, but as soon as I'm calling `opts.region.scale` the error `opts.region is undefined` appears(not opts.region.scale!).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/world.js"></script>
```

Edit: I needed to add another line of code to understand the problem

Comment: `ExtendSomething.extend` seems to be missing a closing bracket, but apart from that, the code you have posted looks okay to me. Why don't you create a JSFiddle snippet?

Comment: I added the closing bracket. What is JSFiddle snippet?

Comment: @Sadik, http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCa2m/) is working fine. It is a bit different from the code you provided though.

Comment: the only difference I can see is: 1.) I'm using world as a subclass with an initialize function, 2.) The different functions appear in seperate files. I still can't understand why I'm getting an `is undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the constructor call with wrong parameters.
There should be some kind of type check, otherwise it gives a TypeError.

remove any wrong call to constructor or add a check

```
square = new World(20, 20, null, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Script files should be loaded in below order.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/world.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainApp.js"></script>
```

It seems we are using objects even before they are being loaded.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that. But this did not solve my problem.